# Python- Extracting elements from a symmetric Matrix

Tags: python-2.7

I have a symmetric matrix of order 'n' and I want to extract only the upper triangular elements into a vector. How to do this in Python?

Comment: How is your matrix represented?

Comment: Sig=  ([S_11, S12, S13.......n],
          [S_12, S22, S_23,....n],
          [S_13, S23, S_33, ...n],
         .
         .
         .
         .
          [S_1n, S_2n, S_3n,.....S_nn]) 

And I want this in a vector form (Column vector) such that all the diagonal elements should come first  the non-diagonal elements. like below
[S_11
S_22
.
.
S_nn
S_12
S_13
.
.
S_1n
S_23
S_24
.
.
]